# How can I get this Javascript to correctly decorate button hyperlinks on my page? Relevant: Google's Cross-Domain Measurement, Unbounce Landing Pages

Tags: javascript, html, google-analytics, tracking, google-analytics-4

I have some [landing pages](https://www.axelgo.app/drs/) built in a service called Unbounce. These landing pages contain buttons going to my sign-up page. The landing pages and sign-up page are in different domains, so I use Google's Cross Domain Measurement to track activity between them.

Unbounced has a behavior in their landing pages where clicks are first directed to an unseen sub-directory and then re-directed to the destination (sign-up page). This behavior causes Google's CDM to not decorate the link, and therefore I am not able to adequately track traffic that goes through my landing pages.

> note: by "not decorated," I mean an "_gl" parameter isn't showing up in the link.

Visiting the provided hyperlink to my [landing page](https://www.axelgo.app/drs/), there's two buttons: "Get Started for FREE" and "Start Your 60-day FREE Trial", at the top and bottom of the page respectively. The top button is subject to the issue I described and the resulting link is not decorated when clicked. The bottom button is not subject to this behavior and produces the desired result when clicked.

I have managed to find examples of people trying to solve similar problems with forms, but it does not work the same for buttons. I'm not sure how to modify this to get it working in my case though. Any help here is appreciated.

```
<script>
  $('.lp-pom-button, .lp-pom-text a, .lp-pom-image a').click(function(event) {
    var parentClass = $(this).parent().attr('class');
    
    var isFormRedirect =
      parentClass === 'lp-element lp-pom-form' &&
      window.module.lp.form.data.confirmAction === 'url' &&
      lp.jQuery('form').valid() === true;

    if (isFormRedirect) {
      ga(function(tracker) {
        var linker = new window.gaplugins.Linker(tracker);
        window.module.lp.form.data.confirmData = linker.decorate(window.module.lp.form.data.confirmData);
      });
    } else {
      ga('linker:decorate', this);
    }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Doesn't look like you can force-decorate your link as easily as in the example you've shown. I would suggest asking Unbounce support team about this. Looks like the link in CTAs are implemented through a redirect, as you've mentioned. That redirect already happens on click. You could, in theory, decorate all urls on the pageview, but I believe Unbounce must have a better solution, like hardcoding the link effectively omitting their redirect. They likely need it for their internal analytics that you don't want to look at anyways.

Comment: @BNazaruk The Unbounced behavior is necessary sadly, as my colleagues want to have tracking in Unbounced as well as GA4. Disabling the redirects will prevent tracking in Unbounced. What's interesting though is that I can manually decorate links from Chromes dev-tools -> console. I used this `new window.gaplugins.Linker(ga.getAll()[0]).decorate('www.axelgo.app')` and it returned a decorated link. I only wish I knew more about JS, as perhaps I could find a way to use this.

Comment: @BNazaruk it would seem that the code I provided is outdated. I can not find this variable: `window.module.lp.form.data.confirmAction`. I'm curious, would you know how I can identify the location of this variable now? If I can create logic to just decorate the variable's value on click, it should work I'd think.

Comment: The code in there wouldn't quite work anyhow. The core idea behind it just wouldn't work, so you don't need it. Again, you'll have to decorate it onload. I thin you may have wrong cross-domain tracking config. Did you go through the steps here for GA4? https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/10071811?hl=en GA4 cross domain tracking is not done via GTM. It's now in GA4's admin section.